# TypeError: RandomForest.<locals>.predict() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, random-forest, cross-validation

I'm using the git repository https://github.com/aimacode/aima-python to do a simple random forest classification final project. The functions that give the error are

```
def cross_validation(learner, dataset, size=None, k=10, trials=1):
    """
    Do k-fold cross_validate and return their mean.
    That is, keep out 1/k of the examples for testing on each of k runs.
    Shuffle the examples first; if trials > 1, average over several shuffles.
    Returns Training error, Validation error
    """
    k = k or len(dataset.examples)
    if trials > 1:
        trial_errT = 0
        trial_errV = 0
        for t in range(trials):
            errT, errV = cross_validation(learner, dataset, size, k, trials)
            trial_errT += errT
            trial_errV += errV
        return trial_errT / trials, trial_errV / trials
    else:
        fold_errT = 0
        fold_errV = 0
        n = len(dataset.examples)
        examples = dataset.examples
        random.shuffle(dataset.examples)
        for fold in range(k):
            train_data, val_data = train_test_split(dataset, fold * (n // k), (fold + 1) * (n // k))
            dataset.examples = train_data
            h = learner(dataset, size)
            fold_errT += err_ratio(h, dataset, train_data)
            fold_errV += err_ratio(h, dataset, val_data)
            # reverting back to original once test is completed
            dataset.examples = examples
        return fold_errT / k, fold_errV / k

def RandomForest(dataset, n=5):
    """An ensemble of Decision Trees trained using bagging and feature bagging."""

    def data_bagging(dataset, m=0):
        """Sample m examples with replacement"""
        n = len(dataset.examples)
        return weighted_sample_with_replacement(m or n, dataset.examples, [1] * n)

    def feature_bagging(dataset, p=0.7):
        """Feature bagging with probability p to retain an attribute"""
        inputs = [i for i in dataset.inputs if probability(p)]
        return inputs or dataset.inputs

    def predict(example):
        print([predictor(example) for predictor in predictors])
        return mode(predictor(example) for predictor in predictors)

    predictors = [DecisionTreeLearner(DataSet(examples=data_bagging(dataset), attrs=dataset.attrs,
                                              attr_names=dataset.attr_names, target=dataset.target,
                                              inputs=feature_bagging(dataset))) for _ in range(n)]

    return predict
```

in learning.py of the above repository.
I tried to do

```
rf_learner = RandomForest(training_dataset)

training_error, validation_error = cross_validation(learner=rf_learner, dataset=training_dataset, size=5) # use the default trials
print('training error for cv:\n', training_error)
print('validation error for cv: \n', validation_error)
```

but it keeps telling me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jlmAurora\Desktop\ISTA 450 final project\code\final_project_classification.py", line 109, in <module>
    training_error, validation_error = cross_validation(learner=rf_learner, dataset=training_dataset, size=5) # delete trial=10 here
  File "C:\Users\jlmAurora\Desktop\ISTA 450 final project\code\learning.py", line 303, in cross_validation
    h = learner(dataset, size)
TypeError: RandomForest.<locals>.predict() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I feel really confused because these are nested functions instead of class methods, then there shouldn't be this error which often occurs when you forgot to specify `self`. 
Could anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You may look for the definition of `RandomForest()`.  You are missing what this is here.

Comment: So I specified the `dataset` parameter and kept `n` as default. I think that's what `RandomForest` takes

Comment: where does that `RandomForest()` class came from? Did you implement your own? I am referring to the line `rf_learner = RandomForest(training_dataset)`.

Comment: `RandomForest()` full code is shown in the first snippet of code, and it's written by someone else. I'm supposed to just take and use it.

Comment: `RandomForest` returns `predict` which you assign to `rf_learner = RandomForest(training_dataset)` and later you send as `cross_validation(learner=rf_learner, ...)` and finally it is executed as `h = learner(dataset, size)` - so it meas `h = predict(dataset, size)` but original function is defined as `def predict(example):` and it expects only one value but you run it with two values.

Comment: omg I didn't realize that. Now I change it to `rf_learner=RandomForest` and it works. Thanks a lot!